# How to do Migrations and SQL Server connection on MacOS

Tags: sql-server, macos, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm in OSX and I'm creating a new ASP.NET Core Web API. I've followed this tutorial: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/netcore/new-db-sqlite.html

That's cool and all but what about Sql Server? Now I know SQL Server won't yet run on OSX (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-on-linux).

The only way I can see to make this work is if I create a cloud remote SQL server (on Azure or similar), then connect with it from my ASP.NET core application. I tried following this, but it assumes VS2015 https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html. We don't have the package manager console in VSCode and I don't know if there is an equivalent to Scaffold-DbContext.

So how do I make a connection to SQLServer and how do I do things like EF migrations to update that database.

Answer (score 1):

All the packages download can be done without the package installer, by using project.json and `dotnet restore` (if VSCode doesn't do it when project.json is saved).

With the tools installed, you can create migrations with `dotnet ef migrations add <migration name>` and `dotnet ef database update` to apply the migrations to the db schema.

Class libraries (where DbContext and models are defined in class library) are not supported yet. There is a workaround in the [Entity Framework Core docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported) though.

For scaffolding the usage is `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold [arguments] [options]`. See the [Scaffolding docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) for details.